# Getting the Name and value as locator

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-ide

Im Using: Selenium IDE (2.9.1), Firefox, Addons - Stored Variables - Selblocks

I am really having issues with locators on a script I'm making and I would like to clear up some confusion I'm having with it.

Their is a webpage that has two big boxes that each contain items in a list. The item will either be in the "unassignedbox" or the "assignedBox".

My issue is that I cant seem to find a way to get specific in my locator.
Command at issue: storeElementPresent|locator|variable1name

Using the selector essentially just applies the value, such as:

```
css=option[value="item1"]
```

This is not ok as the value can be in either box. So its always going to be true. I need to know if its in the assignedBox. The order always changes pending on what values are assigned so I cannot use xpath.

On situations like these I would use the command with the value (this has saved me before) however it does not seem to work. I know its probably a misunderstanding im having about the locators or something but i would love to hear how to have the name and value of an object to be in the locator.

Ive tried:

```
storeElementPresent|name=assignedBox|variable1Name
```

-Find is successful. I can see its their.

```
storeElementPresent|css=select[name="assignedBox"]|variable1Name
```

-Find is successful. I can see its their.

```
storeElementPresent|css=option[value="item1"]|variable1Name
```

-Find is successful. I can see its their.

thats not surprising the name of course is fine alone, but after value applied it fails.

```
storeElementPresent|name=assignedBox value=item1|variable1Name
```

-Find did not find, value is false after running.

```
storeElementPresent|name=assignedBox value="item1"|variable1Name
```

-Find did not find, value is false after running.

```
storeElementPresent|name=assignedBox value='item1'|variable1Name
```

-Find did not find, value is false after running.

```
storeElementPresent|name="assignedBox" value="item1"|variable1Name
```

-Find did not find, value is false after running.

```
storeElementPresent|name='assignedBox' value='item1'|variable1Name
```

-Find did not find, value is false after running.

I know I have a working command that I used on a script before (not on these specific boxes), I reviewed it and its essentially just laid out as `|name=something value=blah|`

Im reaching here a bit maybe I should use the css locator like the selector applies and try something like:

```
css=select[name="assignedBox" value="item1"]
```

or

```
css=option[name="assignedBox" value="item1"]
```

or

`css=select[name="assignedBox"]@value=item1` (this one just finds assignedBox successfully, says true, but doesnt find the specific value, just the assignedbox)
or

```
css=select[name="assignedBox"]value=item1
```

of course those fail as well. I tried with quotes, without quotes, using select, using option...

Ive tried a lot more then the above but I dont think my failed attempts will really help.

Additionally, For the sake of sanity, I have been testing this using a value that has 1 word in its name like value=item1 but their are values with spaces that i need to do this on. It seems like the time I got this running it did not have quotes, and i remember it flat failed when quotes were used. If you answered the above, then could explain how it would also be done when the value has spaces?

Answer (score 0):

When you have spaces use quotes.

Using `[attr1='attr1value'][attr2='attr2value']` means has attribute `attr1` with that value and `attr2` with that value.

You can try something like:

```
css=select[name='assignedBox'][value='item1']
```

For spaces:

```
css=select[name='assignedBox'][value='item 1']
```

Partial match of attribute:

```
css=select[name*=assigned][value*=item]
```

Partial match for name, full match for value using split words:

```
css=select[name*=assigned][value*=item][value*='1']
```

Comment: FYI. This really helped me. The Final answer turned out to be 

storeElementPresent|css=select[name='assignedBox'] option[value='item1']|Variable1Name